# cURL on Debian 7 doesn't seem to use /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

Tags: ssl, curl

When I run the following command:

```
# curl https://undisclosedwebsite.nl
```

I get the following error:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

After some debugging with `openssl s_client -connect https://undisclosedwebsite.nl` I discovered that the following command with cURL does work:

```
curl https://undisclosedwebsite.nl --cacert /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Isn't cURL supposed to use this file?